# How to password protect a file without using software in windows 7

Tags: windows-7, windows, password-protection

How can I have
***`important.txt`***
require the password
***`1qaz2wsx3edc4rfv`*** 
without using software in Windows 7 home premium?

Comment: You cannot.  Windows doesn't have a feature to password protect .txt files.  The file format (.doc, .docx) can support it or you can place it on a volume encrypted by Bitlocker (Enterprise/Ultimate) or use EFS (Professional+) which would require the use to have the certificate.  Voting to close this question to avoid software recommendations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot encrypt a text file without using external software such as TrueCrypt etc.
I'd **recommend** converting it either to a password protected PDF or doc file.
See [this link](https://turbofuture.com/misc/How-to-Password-Protect-a-Text-File):

> The truth is that you really cannot encrypt a .txt file via the file menu or any other sub-menu...

Also, you can make an encrypted disk image and put any file in that container. See [this link](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/35098/whats-the-simplest-way-to-password-protect-a-text-file) on how to accomplish that.

Comment: nvm I think I understand now (:    :D

Comment: Since software recommendations are not advised on Super User, you should conduct your own research for finding out which software suits you best. But I personally use VeraCrypt for my encryption needs.

Comment: A password-protected ZIP file could also work. Unlike a PDF or MS Word document, you can be assured that the decrypted result is identical to the original text file.